# Chrome tts voice alternates between female and male?

Tags: google-chrome, text-to-speech, webspeech-api

We have the weirdest problem. We are using the Web Speech TTS engine on Chrome, and selecting the Google UK English Female using the API SpeechSynthesis.getVoices()
however, when speaking, the voice alternates between the female voice to an unfamiliar male voice.

EDIT: click on Speak here:
https://codepen.io/lmessinger/pen/yLvPdVX?editors=1010

And we are wondering, what is *he* doing here? how did he get inside? what's going on?

any help/idea would be appreciated

thanks!

Lior

Comment: I use this for a clue system for an escape room, ours alternates to a woman who has COVID, to a posh UK English voice and others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Speech Synthesis Google Voices do NOT respect selected voice for circa ±20% of utterances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72980017/speech-synthesis-google-voices-do-not-respect-selected-voice-for-circa-%c2%b120-of-u)